# passing function as a prop to child component in React throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-props

Are there any specific guidelines when passing callbacks as props to child components in React?

At some point my code ina app.js looks the following:

```
test() {
  
}
  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MiniDrawer handleProductChange={this.handleProductChange.bind(this)} product={{icon:'', name:'Magnifier', height:'20px'}}/>
      <div className='inrow'> 
      <PowerbiEmbedded
          id={this.state.ReportId}
          embedUrl={"https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId="+this.state.ReportId+"&groupId="+this.state.workspaceId}
          accessToken={this.state.accesstoken}
          filterPaneEnabled={true}
          navContentPaneEnabled={true}
          bookmarksPaneEnabled={true}
         test={() => this.test}
          //pageName={`${YOUR_PAGE_ID}`}
          //embedType={`Report`}
          tokenType={0}
          width='100%'
          height='1000px'
        />
    </div>
    </div>
    
  );}
```

The MiniDrawer component does not signal any issues with handleProductChange callback. While simple callback which I am trying to pass to PowerBiEmbedded component fails with error:

DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': () => this.test could not be cloned.
I managed to extract the source of the problem. There is a function inside the child component using props with Object.assign. If i comment out this function error disappears. What can I do about it?

```
updateState (props) {
    const nextState = Object.assign({}, this.state, props, {
      pageName: this.props.pageName,
      settings: {
       /* panes:{
          bookmarks: {visible: this.props.bookmarkPaneEnabled},
          filters: {visible: this.props.filterPaneEnabled},
          pageNavigation: {visible: this.props.navContentPaneEnabled}
        },*/
        filterPaneEnabled: this.props.filterPaneEnabled,
        navContentPaneEnabled: this.props.navContentPaneEnabled,
        bookmarkPaneEnabled: this.props.bookmarkPaneEnabled,
        layoutType: this.props.mobile ? pbi.models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait : undefined
      },
      type: this.props.embedType ? this.props.embedType : 'report'
    })
```

Any ideas what am I missing in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the solution. Object assign method for some reason fails to copy react callback '[native code]' issue. I'll let the purist to debate on that. I do not need the callback in this new object as it is passed further, and it is intended to have other properties, I simply clone the props myself with function removed ("zonk") in the example. Obviously this could be extended to verify the typeof key to make it more generic.

```
updateState (props) {
  var distilledProps = _objectWithoutProperties(props, ['zonk'])
  console.log(distilledProps)
    const nextState = Object.assign({}, this.state, distilledProps, {
      pageName: this.props.pageName,
      settings: {
       /* panes:{
          bookmarks: {visible: this.props.bookmarkPaneEnabled},
          filters: {visible: this.props.filterPaneEnabled},
          pageNavigation: {visible: this.props.navContentPaneEnabled}
        },*/
        filterPaneEnabled: this.props.filterPaneEnabled,
        navContentPaneEnabled: this.props.navContentPaneEnabled,
        bookmarkPaneEnabled: this.props.bookmarkPaneEnabled,
        layoutType: this.props.mobile ? pbi.models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait : undefined
      },
      type: this.props.embedType ? this.props.embedType : 'report'
    })
```

... and helper function:

```
function _objectWithoutProperties(obj, keys) {
  var target = {};
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (keys.indexOf(i) >= 0) continue;
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) continue;
    target[i] = obj[i];
  }
  return target;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to omit the arrow function when passing the callback as prop like this

`test={this.test}`

Comment: Yields the same result:-(

Comment: ok somehow it looks like the problem is the `test` function itself – does it work if you put a debugger, or console.log in the first line of `function test()` ?

Comment: yes. it does work. I just invoked it from handleProductChange callback.

Comment: well okay then the props passing isn't the problem and you need to fix your `test` function

Comment: I tested it with different component import React, { Component } from 'react';
class test extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props)
    }
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.test('parameter passed')
}
}
export default test

Comment: and it works: <testComponent test={this.test.bind(this)}/>, but when I try to pass it to exactly <PowerbiEmbedded> component it throws above error. What can be wrong with child component to present this behaviour

Comment: DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': function () { [native code] } could not be cloned.

Comment: hard to tell without the full code at hand can you create a sandbox oder codepen for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind your function because you are using a class, try that :

```
test={test.bind(this)}
```